# NSDictionary creation inside loop with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary

I'm having a big trouble while creating NSDictionaries inside a for-loop while using ARC. The point is that after the first "dict" creation, the app crashes giving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS so I presume it's something related to the release of the object, but can't figure out what! I tried using an autoreleasepool but the result was the same

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arr1 count]; i++) {
        __strong NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[arr1 objectAtIndex:i], @"name", [arr4 objectAtIndex:i], @"position", [arr2 objectAtIndex:i], @"number", [arr5 objectAtIndex:i], @"status", [[arr6 objectAtIndex:i] intValue], @"order", nil];
        [pl_stuff addObject:dict];
}
```

thanks for your replies

Comment: what can be content of the arr1

Comment: pl_stuff is an array, the problem was, as Vladimir mentioned, that I was adding an int inside the dictionary which was inserted to an array. Thanks for the quick answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[arr6 objectAtIndex:i] intValue]
```

You're trying to add plain integer value to your array, but array accept only objective-c objects. You should probably just leave that as:

```
[arr6 objectAtIndex:i]
```

Comment: oh gosh, I didn't think about the problem of inserting an int inside the dictionary and then the dictionary inside the array. Well, that was the problem, thank you very much